# EstimatedProcess hangs with documentation example

Tags: probability-or-statistics, bugs

Not sure if this is a bug or a typo but for the first example of the `ARMAProcess` in *Mathematica* 9 we have:

```
data = Select[WeatherData["Champaign", "Temperature", {2012, 8}], 
              FreeQ[#, Missing] &][[All, 2]];
temp = TemporalData[data]
eproc = EstimatedProcess[temp, ARMAProcess[3, 3]]
```

`EstimatedProcess` hangs, whereas if I just send the data (with `RLink`!) to R's `arima` solver (with `order=c(3,0,3)` so it is an ARMA model), it solves instantly, and all further analysis looks the same as the example, so it isn't given a bad solution or anything.

Is there something wrong with the documentation (reminds me of the issues of trying to do optimization without using `?NumericQ` variables).

Any thoughts? Really want to use this feature...

Comment: @Jens while this is new functionality, it was decided that the current version _does not_ need a [version tag](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/80/52), and that the most recent version should be automatically assumed.

Comment: Takes about 11 seconds on my machine (Win 7 64-bit 8GB RAM)

Comment: @rcollyer OK - I've also removed it from the `UnitConvert` question (that's where I saw the tag and thought it should be added to other questions too).

Comment: @Jens cool. I asked that the question on meta be tagged as featured, so that it will show in the community bulletin.

Comment: @AndyRoss strange mine has been running for an hour. I have tried it on two different machines, both windows 7 64 bit. Can anyone else reproduce the 11sec? (which is still slowish ... but not what I am talking about)

Comment: Got the result `ARMAProcess[{1.76657, -0.778926, -0.0432089}, {-0.377455, -0.0539874, -0.0342011}, 1.41441]` in less than 10 seconds (Windows Vista 64 bit 8Gb memory dual core 2.8GHz laptop)

Comment: Ugh okay must be something on my end ... need to call the Wolfram people. Should I delete this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just in case anyone else is having the same problem I did a complete removal of Mathematica versions 8 and 9, including all Application Data folders. Then did a fresh install and The code now runs in around 5s on my i5-2500k/8g ram windows 7 system. Not sure what the issue was, but this did fix the problem.

**Update**

Well seems this "solution" was premature, as the problem is back. Seems this is a known issue at Wolfram and should be fixed in the future.